# Probability of hanging n keys on n hooks

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

Question:

a) One evening, a bemused lodge-porter tried to hang $n$ keys on their $n$ hooks, but only managed to hang them independently and at random. There was no limit to the number of keys which could be hung on any hook. Otherwise, find an expression for the probability that at least one key was hung on its own hook.

b) The following morning, the porter was rebuked by the Bursar, so that in the evening she was careful to hang only one key on each hook. But she still only managed to hang them independently and at random. Find an expression for the probability that no key was then hung on its
own hook.

Find the limits of both expressions as $n$ tends to infinity

I know how to find the number of ways that the hooks can be placed using combinatorics methods, but I don't know how to find the probabilities of these events. Does the probability use combinatorics? Is there a simple formula I don't know? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have $k$ hooks and $n$ keys. You may think of $k = n$, but for the sake of clarity, I'd like to (for the moment) use different variables. I'd like to think of the hooks as letters and the keys as positions in a string. For each key, we may select a hook in $k$ ways. There are $n$ such keys, so there are $k^{n}$ ways of placing the keys on the hooks.

For (a), take the count you got and divide by $k^{n}$ (in this case, $k = n$, so divide by $n^n$). Here, the probability is a relative frequency. In particular, we are selecting a configuration of keys on hooks uniformly at random (that is, we are selecting the configuration uniformly at random).

For (b), our sample space is now permutations. We have $n!$ permutations. How many ways are there of placing $n$ keys on $n$ hooks, so that no key is on its own hook?

> The number here is the derangement number. Have you had a chance to work out the inclusion-exclusion expression for derangements?